# How to stop audio with pyglet when file is played?

Tags: audio, loops, media, pyglet, playback

I'm using this program to play na audio file:

music = pyglet.resource.media('file.wav')
music.play()

pyglet.app.run()

I have a problem: I can't do anything after this program. How to stop the audio file when is played? It's look like a loop.

Comment: This answer uses SPACE bar to pause/resume video playing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62506039/1769859

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to include add an eventlistener for the [on_eos](http://pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.media.Player-class.html#on_eos) event.

For an example have a look as this thread on the [pyglet Google group](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/pyglet-users/browse_thread/thread/636ff6c62deeacf3/d20b33c85c60bcbb?lnk=gst&q=on_eos#d20b33c85c60bcbb).